# Creating is_sold MySQL field based on index existence in another table

Tags: mysql

I have a simple set of products with serial numbers. If a product is sold, its serial number gets placed in `sold_items` while all items that ever existed remain in `all_items`.

Some sample data:

```
all_items
id | serial_number | product_name | product_price
1  | XXXXXXXXXXX01 | Laptop       | 199
2  | XXXXXXXXXXX02 | Tablet       | 99

sold_items
id | serial_number | sold_time
1  | XXXXXXXXXXX02 | [TIMESTAMP]
```

I'm trying to do something like this with my query:

```
SELECT 
  all_items.* , 
  (JOIN sold_items ON sold_items.serial_number = all_items.serial_number) AS is_sold
FROM all_items
```

In this case, the expected output would be

```
[
  0=>[
    'id'=>1,
    'serial_number'=>XXXXXXXXXXX01,
    'product_name'=>Laptop,
    'product_price'=>199,
    'is_sold'=>0
  ],
  1=>[
    'id'=>1,
    'serial_number'=>XXXXXXXXXXX02,
    'product_name'=>Tablet,
    'product_price'=>99,
    'is_sold'=>1
  ]
]
```

Is this easily achievable with a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` and test whether the ID in the other table is not null.

```
SELECT a.*, s.id IS NOT NULL AS is_sold
FROM all_items AS a
LEFT JOIN sold_items AS s ON a.serial_number = s.serial_number
```